# ORA-06553 wrong arguments with java function in Oracle with Blob

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, blob

I am trying to implement a function in Oracle 11g which calls a java class to decrypt Blob image information.

Everything seems valid, but I get a ORA-06553 PLS-306 "wrong number or types of arguments"

The function takes a blob and returns a blob so I don't see where the error is coming from.

PL/SQL function:

```
create or replace
function decrypt_image return blob as
language JAVA name 'Imageutil.decryptBlobImage (java.sqlBlob) return java.sqlBlob';
```

Java function:

```
public class Imageutil
public static java.sql.Blob decryptBlobImage (java.sql.Blob img) throws Exception {
    try {
        int len = (int)img.length();
        byte[] imagearray = img.getBytes(1, len);
        byte[] decrypted = Encryptor.decryptBinary(imagearray);
        Blob retval = new SerialBlob(decrypted);
        return retval;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("Error handling blob",ex);
    }
}
}
```

The data is in a table:

```
temp_image(id number, image blob, decrypted blob);
```

I am trying to

```
update temp_image set decrypted = decrypt_image(image);
```

When I get the error. An Oracle trc file is generated each time, but the there doesn't appear to be an error:

```
========= Dump for error ORA 1110 (no incident) ========
----- DDE Action: 'DB_STRUCTURE_INTEGRITY_CHECK' (Async) -----
```

(it then does an integrity check of the database).

The function works, the original data is a long raw, and I can take a hex dump of the data and decrypt it fine. The test table was loaded by a to_lob() function on the original long raw data.

Comment: "The functiion works" - which function works? Do you mean the Java method works, if called outside the database?

Comment: The Encryptor.decyrptBinary function works when called from a java main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have `java.sqlBlob` instead of `java.sql.Blob` in the PL/SQL declaration; but you also aren't supplying an argument for your function inthat declaraion:

```
create or replace
function decrypt_image (original_blob blob) return blob as
language JAVA name 'Imageutil.decryptBlobImage (java.sql.Blob) return java.sql.Blob';
```

Woth your version the PL/SQL function doesn't take an argument, so when you call it as `decrypt_image(image)` you *are* passing the wrong number of arguments - it is expecting none but you pass one.

Comment: This is it exactly. I was all "what's wrong with my java" rather than "what's wrong with my PL/SQL".